# What do you call a person who is polite but deceiving?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language, epithet-requests

I remember a quote from a while ago that went somewhere along the line *x is saying ´fuck you´ to a person but making them feel flattered*

It's a quality that makes somebody polite, manipulative and tactful.

Comment: I'd call that person a *politician*....

Answer (score 1):

A **saccharine** person is one with an overly sweet but insincere personality. Such a person is likely to be excessively kind on the surface but manipulative underneath, quite capable of giving backhanded compliments.

> 4. cloyingly agreeable or ingratiating: *a saccharine personality.*
> 5. exaggeratedly sweet or sentimental: *a saccharine smile; a saccharine song of undying love.*

Source: [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/saccharine)

Comment: I think the poster is looking for a word that suggests a stronger negative than merely being insincere or phony. Someone can be "saccharine" without concealing active malevolence.